# Adding an action to Android custom notifications

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have read the Android developer guide about notifications and I've created one like it showed:

```
private static void initNotificationCompatObject()
{
    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon).setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Test!");
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
}
```

The notification itself is displayed and working.

What I want to do is add another action to do after the notification is pressed. I want to read the notification Id in my activity (or in some sort of action listener of the builder) and do something depends on the Id. How can something like that be acheived?

Comment: do u mean, you show multiple notification and want to do separate action for each notification based on id?

Comment: I got several notifications thats true, but for each one all I know how to do is just open an activity. I want to do some stuff in the onCreate (or in a listener that is attached to each builder) based on the id of the notification.

Comment: After you click on the notification, your `MainActivity` gets called. You can fetch the data from the notification in that and play with it as per your requirement.

Comment: @PrerakSola that is exactly my question - how do I fetch the data from the notification?

Comment: you have to pass the notification id in resultIntent  and as usual in Activity , u can use getIntent(). r u asking this ? or something else

Comment: if I can use the getIntent to get it from the notification and read what notification id was pressed then yes. I wanted to see an example of how exactly should I send it and then how to read it after the notification was pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID_FIRST = 1000;
  public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID_SECOND = 1002;
  notify(NOTIFICATION_ID_FIRST);
  notify(NOTIFICATION_ID_SECOND);
```

Notification:

```
    private static void notify(int id)
    {

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon).setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Test!");
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("NOTIFICATION_ID", String.valueOf(id));
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);


        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(id , mBuilder.build());
    }
```

MainActivity:

```
        int notificationId = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("NOTIFICATION_ID"));
        if(notificationId == NOTIFICATION_ID_FIRST){
            //handle
        }else if (notificationId == NOTIFICATION_ID_SECOND){
            ...
        }
```